# onkeyup not working when delete keyword using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, callback

I have a sample code:

```
<input type="text" class="" id="key" name="key" value="ex: IPhone 4S" 
    onfocus="cleanPhoneBox(this);" 
    onblur="fillPhoneBox(this);" 
    onkeyup="javascript:search_phones('demo.php');">
```

And javascript

```
function cleanPhoneBox( obj ) {
    if( obj.value == obj.defaultValue ) {
        obj.value = '';
        obj.className = '';
    }
}

function fillPhoneBox( obj ) {
    if( obj.value == '' ) {
        obj.value = obj.defaultValue;
        obj.className = 'search_tool_tip';
    }
}

var lasttimeout = 0;
function search_phones(ajaxdomain) {
    search_string = $('#key').val();    
    if(search_string.length >= 2) {
        if( lasttimeout ) clearTimeout(lasttimeout);
        lasttimeout = setTimeout('search_phones_call(\"'+ajaxdomain+'\", \"'+search_string+'\")', 300 );
    }
}

function search_phones_call( ajaxdomain, search_string ) {
    $('#searchPhoneResultsContainer').empty();
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : ajaxdomain + '?jsoncallback=?',
        data: {
            action: "dialog",
            type: "searchPhonesJSON",
            query: search_string,
            itemsCount: 100,
            nocache: 96316638
        },
        dataType:'json'
    }); 
}
```

When I search with keyword: "`iphone 4`" is result call json ajax OK, but when `delete keyword`, and `search again` is result can't call ajax json callback, how to fix it

Comment: So the issue is the `delete` keyword not yielding results when making an AJAX request not the actual `keyup` event itself? Have you verified that server actually returns results when the `delete` keyword is used?

Answer (score 0):

You're dynamically building a function call string into `setTimeout` which calls Javascript's `eval` command. It's best to avoid string arguments to `setTimeout` for just this sort of reason.

Try letting JQuery manage the callback:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url : ajaxdomain,
        cache : false,
        data: {
            action: "dialog",
            type: "searchPhonesJSON",
            query: search_string,
            itemsCount: 100
        },
        dataType:'jsonp'
    })
    .then(function(data)
    {
        // what you want to do with the server response goes here
    });
```

But if you want to just fix your `setTimeout` code, use an anonymous function:

```
lasttimeout = setTimeout(function()
{
    search_phones_call(ajaxdomain, search_string)
}, 300);
```